# Storing a random generating code into a session, without it re-generating when echoing the session

Tags: php, session

I am generating a random code.

```
function GenerateID($email) 
{
    $nums = substr(hash('sha512', $email), 0, 10);
    $ID = strtoupper(str_shuffle($nums));
    return $ID;
}
```

And then I store it into a session

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $ID;
```

and then I select that ID from the database, and then the ID changes because whenever I activate it, it regenerates instead of staying the same.

```
            $makesure = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
            $makesure->bindValue(':id', $ID);
            $makesure->execute();
```

How can I make it stop regenerating? is there a better solution than using separate files?

The function generateID is located in functions.inc.php
I am handling it at index.php.

Basically I made a quick registration system, where user puts his email and clicks submit, and then he receives a unique generated String.

There can be multiple users with same email, but ID must be different.

So this is how I am selecting the specify just registered user:

```
        $fetch = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND :id LIMIT 1");
        $fetch->bindValue(':email', $_SESSION['email']);
        $fetch->bindValue(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
        $fetch->execute();
```

But this is doing nothing, because I assume the session ID regenerates while it's being executed.

Comment: we're missing crucial information. What different files do you use and at what level is your code executed.. Please elaborate your code.

Comment: Edited it a bit, still thinking of what to include.

Comment: No answers? For some reason.